# jQuery Slide Elements appearing below each other (should be side by side)

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, slide

I have a tutorial box, which has about 4 slides ([2 for this (demo)](https://jsfiddle.net/3phsesjc/3/embedded/result/)).

[image]

My aim is to get the slides to slide right to left as the user clicks next. I have managed to get this to work, however the elements display one on top of the other - rather than side by side.
[image]

I've used jQuery UI to achieved this:

```
function guide() {
    // Controls for the welcome guide
    //guideCurrentItem = guideCurrentItem + 1;
    $("#1").hide('slide', { direction: 'left' }, 2000);
    $("#2").show('slide', { direction: 'right' }, 2000);
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="welcome">
    <div class="holder">
        <div class="item" id="1">
            <div class="hero">

            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <h1>Read online, quickly and easily.</h1>
                <p>Get started now with our user guide, or <a href="/Home/Read">jump ahead</a> if you know you're setup.</p>
                <p class="align-center"><span class="button" onclick="guide()">Next</span></p>
                <div class="dots">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
            <div class="item offscreen" id="2">
                <div class="hero">

                </div>
                <div class="content">
                    <h1>Connect.</h1>
                    <p></p>
                    <p>Get started now with our user guide, or <a href="/Home/Read">jump ahead</a> if you know you're setup.</p>
                    <p class="align-center"><span class="button">Next</span></p>
                    <div class="dots">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <div class="spacing"></div>
        <p class="align-center"><input type="checkbox" id="chkShowHelp" checked /> Hide this welcome screen the next time I visit</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I make it so that they display side by side in the most efficient way possible? I have tried all the combinations of display:inline-block etc but can't get it to work.

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3phsesjc/3/)

*Ps. Yes I know there are lots of plugins that do this - but that doesn't exactly help the knowledge bank.*

Comment: your divs dont fit in the parent div

Comment: make the divs smaller or the parent bigger

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give `.item` a `position: absolute;` https://jsfiddle.net/3phsesjc/4/

After that you just need to style it to look better.

```
    .welcome .holder .item {
        position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the general idea with sliders is to have an items wrapper with 
width = items * items_width and then move around this wrapper to go to the selected item.

```
    <div class="holder">
       <div class="items-wrapper" style='width:900px'>
         <div class="item" id="1"></div>
         <div class="item" id="2"></div>
       </div>
    </div>
```

with this approach you dont have to show or hide your elements you just need to change the marginLeft value of items-wrapper. 
You can do your math with jquery and your animations with css